# What is an adjective that describes 'one way' and 'two way' flow?

Tags: terminology

A few example are in order:

**One way flow**

1. An injection.
2. A river flowing into an ocean.
3. A mothers love.

**Two way flow**

1. Phone calls.
2. The flow of water between two oceans.
3. Herpies.

So, as you can see, all these things share the same property informally called 'flow', though it can only be one of two things in any point in time. As said property seems to be quite universal, I was wondering if there's an official term for what I dub 'one way flow', and 'two way flow'.

Comment: As in unidirectional and bidirectional?

Comment: **One-way** and **two-way** are formal/official terms.

Comment: @NVS, their to vague a terms though. So if something is 'two way', that could mean many different things, which is why I gave example. Such an official term wouldn't need examples.

Comment: @HughMeyers I like it, though it still doesn't seem to be exactly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websters gives the following definitions of [unidirectional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unidirectional)

> 1:  involving, functioning, moving, or responsive in a single
>   direction
>
> 2:  not subject to change or reversal of direction

and [bidirectional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bidirectional)

> involving, moving, or taking place in two usually opposite directions

I think those meet your needs. Specific to phone calls would be [duplex](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duplex) for bidirectional. Half duplex communication is bidirectional but only one direction at a time.

Comment: I recommend using the "block quote" format for the definitions you've quoted. :)